# Prevent inserting a line db if an input type="date" is not filled

Tags: php, html, sql, codeigniter

I want to make a form where the user can choose what he would like to answer.

The only problem here is the input type="date". Even if this kind of input is untouched, my code is creating a row in my database.
Making me a row with a blank.
I tried to put value="" in my input type="date" but that doesn't work. 
This is the only kind of input that bother me, the others input type don't create any row if the user don't enter anything.

Here is the input I want to create no row in my db if it's not filled:

```html
<form action="<?php echo base_url('tbl_reponse/submit') ?>" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
...
<input name="date" type="date" class="form-control">
```

Comment: So what's the problem with checking data passed to server?

Comment: Checking if this post isset () would be doable, but I wanted to know if an input type="date" can have a default value like null from the html.
And I don't understand because the other type of input don't create anything.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&ei=GfH7XJSlFsj7z7sPhfKG4AM&q=check+a+string+is+date+stackoverflow&oq=check+a+sting+is+date+stackover&gs_l=psy-ab.3.1.33i22i10i29i30l2.43886.46016..48747...0.0..0.165.1695.0j12......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j35i304i39j0i22i30j0i13i5i30j0i8i13i30.vwQ4zagF-ME

Comment: Do you want it to be null or have it required to be filled in? You may use `value=""` if you want to allow an empty date or `required="required"` if you want to force the user to fill in a date.

Comment: Problem solved by checking the data like this 
```foreach($useranswers as $key => $item) {
      $useranswers[$key]=str_replace("\r\n","",$item);
      if ($item===""){
        unset($useranswers[$key]);
      }
    }```

Comment: SO AT LAST, you did do it on the server.